# WordPress query - order by date and alternate by category

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type called "services" with a custom taxonomy called "location". Each post is categorized as either "Location A" or "Location B".

I need to query all posts from the "services" post type, and order them by date. However, rather than simply list by date, I want to alternate posts by each category, like so:

1. Newest post from "Location A"
2. Newest post from "Location B"
3. 2nd newest post from "Location A"
4. 2nd newest post from "Location B"
5. 3rd newest post from "Location A"
6. 3rd newest post from "Location B"
   etc...

Is it possible to modify the following query to achieve this? Or do I have to do some advanced database joining/merging (not as familiar with that method)?

```
<?php $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'services', 
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'order_by' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'location',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array ('location-a', 'location-b')
                )
            )
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if (have_posts()) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

Additional notes:

- There won't be an even number of posts in each category, so I need the query to continue listing the posts from Location A, once you run out of posts from Location B, and vice versa.
- What happens if a post has been categorized in both categories? I don't want it to show
  twice.
- The custom taxonomy "location" is shared by several different post types. But I only want to query one post type at a time.
- I need to retain the ability to make certain posts sticky.

Is this possible? Thanks so much.

Comment: I have tested and retested my code and it works. I think that you have somewhere made a mistake with your values. I have moved my answer to WPSE now as it will be more useful there

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I did. If you're getting a correct result, I must have made a mistake. I will re-test with your code and take a closer look. It seems you've removed your answer, but if I'm able to get your code to work, I'd like to mark it correct because it was more streamlined.

Comment: For anyone interested, @PieterGoosen code worked and is a bit more efficient than the answer below, although that answer is also correct. You can find Pieter's code here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168053/custom-query-alternate-posts-by-category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the code if it is working for you . Sorry, the code is too long

```
<?php
$a1 = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'services',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'location-a'
        )
    ),
    'fields' => 'ids' // only get post IDs.
));
$a2 = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'services',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'location-b'
        )
    ),
    'fields' => 'ids' // only get post IDs.
));
if (count($a1) >= count($a2)) {

    $count = count($a1);

} else {
    $count = count($a2);

}

$newArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $newArray[] = $a1[$i];
    $newArray[] = $a2[$i];
}


$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post__in' => $newArray,
    'orderby' => 'post__in'
));

if ($wp_query -> have_posts()):
    while ($wp_query -> have_posts()):
        the_post();

        echo get_the_title() . '<br>';
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: This can be done in one query with proper sorting :-). Just a tip, never use `query_posts`. The correct functions to use here is either `WP_Query` or `get_posts`

Comment: @ Pieter Goosen Thanx for the advise i will keep it in mind..Can you post a good solution it will help all of us in future

Comment: i have made chnegs as suggested by Pieter

Comment: Will have a look if I have time tonight :-) I think that this is a question worth answering. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Thank you for offering a solution. I will test this out and come back to let you know if it worked for me!

Comment: @ManuA Please see my answer. This is what I came up with. I did not have the time yet to test this as yet, will most probably try to test tonight. Any feedback will be appreciated

Comment: @ Pieter Goosen thanx for the solution it does look good to me..but i will tested it let you know